# Getting error while installing Expo modules in React Native iOS Application

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, cocoapods

I have an application in react-native with minimum iOS version set to 11. I am using Cocoapods as dependency manager. I need to install expo-web-browser and for that I am following [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-web-browser) link. So first I need to install [Expo modules](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/). But when I run the command `npx install-expo-modules@latest`,it forces me to update minimum iOS requirement to 12 and after that I get the following error:

Found some duplicated unimodule packages. Installed the ones with the highest version number.
Make sure following dependencies of your project are resolving to one specific version:
expo-file-system, expo-constants

Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `UMCore` in `Podfile`:

- UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)
- UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)

**Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Uncaught Error CocoaPodsError: Command `pod install` failed.**
└─ Cause: There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `UMCore` in `Podfile`:

- UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)
- UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)

Comment: Did you found the solution for this ?